# How to plot ROC curve in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, roc

I am trying to plot a ROC curve to evaluate the accuracy of a prediction model I developed in Python using logistic regression packages. I have computed the true positive rate as well as the false positive rate; however, I am unable to figure out how to plot these correctly using `matplotlib` and calculate the AUC value. How could I do that?

Answer (score 156):

Here are two ways you may try, assuming your `model` is an sklearn predictor:

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
# calculate the fpr and tpr for all thresholds of the classification
probs = model.predict_proba(X_test)
preds = probs[:,1]
fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, preds)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

# method I: plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()

# method II: ggplot
from ggplot import *
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fpr = fpr, tpr = tpr))
ggplot(df, aes(x = 'fpr', y = 'tpr')) + geom_line() + geom_abline(linetype = 'dashed')
```

or try

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = 'fpr', ymin = 0, ymax = 'tpr')) + geom_line(aes(y = 'tpr')) + geom_area(alpha = 0.2) + ggtitle("ROC Curve w/ AUC = %s" % str(roc_auc))
```

Comment: So 'preds' is basically your predict_proba scores and 'model' is your classifier?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen preds is y hat; yes, model is the trained classifier

Comment: What is `all thresholds`, how they are computed?

Comment: @mrgloom they are chosen automatically by sklearn.metrics.roc_curve

Answer (score 118):

This is the simplest way to plot an ROC curve, given a set of ground truth labels and predicted probabilities. Best part is, it plots the ROC curve for ALL classes, so you get multiple neat-looking curves as well

```
import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = # ground truth labels
y_probas = # predicted probabilities generated by sklearn classifier
skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve(y_true, y_probas)
plt.show()
```

Here's a sample curve generated by plot_roc_curve. I used the sample digits dataset from scikit-learn so there are 10 classes. Notice that one ROC curve is plotted for each class.

[image: ROC Curves]

Disclaimer: Note that this uses the [scikit-plot](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot) library, which I built.

Comment: How to calculate `y_true ,y_probas `  ?

Comment: Reii Nakano - You're a genius in the disguise of an angel. You have made my day. This package is soooo simple but yet oh so effective. You have my full respect. Just a little note on your code snippet above; the line before last shouln't it read: `skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve(y_true, y_probas)`? A big thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! In fact this answer was written before v0.3, and the syntax is now deprecated. Will update with the correct one now! Thanks!

Comment: This should have been selected as the correct answer! Very useful package

Comment: Great package. It will be very useful if you can add to your answer how to get `y_probas` for the sake of completion and easy understanding (or provide a good link for it).

Comment: I am having problems trying to use package. Everytime I am trying to feed the plot roc curve, it tells me I have "too many  indices". I am feeding the my y_test and , pred to it. I am able to hae my predictions. But cant get the plot becuase of that error. Is it due to the version of python I am running?

Comment: I had to reshape my y_pred data to be of size Nx1 instead of just a list: y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1). Now I am instead getting the error 'IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1', but a figure is drawn, which I guess is because the code expects a binary classifier to provide a Nx2 vector with each class probability

Comment: This is for those who are having problem. y_truth is the class that the instance belongs to. So in case, you have class in form of [0 1], you have to use argmax(axis=1) and then pass only the true class, y_probas is the probabilities of all the classes such as [0.4 0.6]. If you want only class, then you have to convert problabilities in 0 or 1. In case of [0.4 0.6] use [0 1].

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque `y_probas = model.predict_proba(X_test)` should generate the `y_probas`. `y_true` are just the actual true values. So you may well have them as `y_test` or something similar.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Error: too many indices as reported by @Herc01.

Comment: The things have to be, for example (if doing binary classification of three samples) `plot_roc_curve([1,0,0], [[0.8,0.2],[0.1,0.9],[0.99,0.1]] )`

Comment: I had the same too many indices error when using data from binary classification, then realized that my predictions were not Nx2 array but N array (so I had to change it to array something like `Nx(1-pred, pred)`

Comment: @rnso https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/pull/98 here is an example of using the package that I could find :) happy plotting

Answer (score 68):

## AUC curve For Binary Classification using matplotlib

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#### Load Breast Cancer Dataset

```
breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer()

X = breast_cancer.data
y = breast_cancer.target
```

#### Split the Dataset

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.33, random_state=44)
```

#### Model

```
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

#### Accuracy

```
print("Accuracy", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

#### AUC Curve

```
y_pred_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[::,1]
fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test,  y_pred_proba)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="data 1, auc="+str(auc))
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```

[image: AUC Curve]

Answer (score 47):

It is not at all clear what the problem is here, but if you have an array `true_positive_rate` and an array `false_positive_rate`, then plotting the ROC curve and getting the AUC is as simple as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = # false_positive_rate
y = # true_positive_rate 

# This is the ROC curve
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show() 

# This is the AUC
auc = np.trapz(y,x)
```

Comment: this answer would have been much better if there were FPR, TPR oneliners in the code.

Comment: fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, preds)

Comment: what does 'metrics' means here? what's that exactly?

Comment: @dekio 'metrics' here is from sklearn: from sklearn import metrics

Comment: fpr[i],tpr[i] should be false positive and true positive rate based on the threshold i, fpr is the num of  y negative above threshold over num of all negative sample while tpr is num of y positive above threshold over num of all positive sample

Answer (score 26):

Here is python code for computing the ROC curve (as a scatter plot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

score = np.array([0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.55, 0.54, 0.53, 0.52, 0.51, 0.505, 0.4, 0.39, 0.38, 0.37, 0.36, 0.35, 0.34, 0.33, 0.30, 0.1])
y = np.array([1,1,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 0, 1, 0])

# false positive rate
fpr = []
# true positive rate
tpr = []
# Iterate thresholds from 0.0, 0.01, ... 1.0
thresholds = np.arange(0.0, 1.01, .01)

# get number of positive and negative examples in the dataset
P = sum(y)
N = len(y) - P

# iterate through all thresholds and determine fraction of true positives
# and false positives found at this threshold
for thresh in thresholds:
    FP=0
    TP=0
    for i in range(len(score)):
        if (score[i] > thresh):
            if y[i] == 1:
                TP = TP + 1
            if y[i] == 0:
                FP = FP + 1
    fpr.append(FP/float(N))
    tpr.append(TP/float(P))

plt.scatter(fpr, tpr)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You used same "i" outer loop index in the inner loop too.

Comment: Reference is 404.

Answer (score 16):

```
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = # true labels
y_probas = # predicted results
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_probas, pos_label=0)

# Print ROC curve
plt.plot(fpr,tpr)
plt.show() 

# Print AUC
auc = np.trapz(tpr,fpr)
print('AUC:', auc)
```

Comment: How to calculate `y_true = # true labels,
y_probas = # predicted results` ?

Comment: If you have the ground truth, y_true is your ground truth (label), y_probas is the predicted results from your model

Answer (score 13):

Based on multiple comments from stackoverflow, scikit-learn documentation and some other, I made a python package to plot ROC curve (and other metric) in a really simple way.

To install package : `pip install plot-metric` (more info at the end of post)

To plot a ROC Curve (example come from the documentation) :

### Binary classification

Let's load a simple dataset and make a train & test set :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2, weights=[1,1], random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=2)
```

Train a classifier and predict test set :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=23)
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Use predict_proba to predict probability of the class
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

You can now use plot_metric to plot ROC Curve :

```
from plot_metric.functions import BinaryClassification
# Visualisation with plot_metric
bc = BinaryClassification(y_test, y_pred, labels=["Class 1", "Class 2"])

# Figures
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
bc.plot_roc_curve()
plt.show()
```

Result :
[image: ROC Curve]

You can find more example of on the github and documentation of the package:

- Github : https://github.com/yohann84L/plot_metric
- Documentation : https://plot-metric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I have tried this and it's nice but doesn't seems like it works only if classification labels were 0 or 1 but if I have 1 and 2 it doesn't work (as labels), do you know how to solve this? and also seem impossible to edit the graph (like the legend)

Comment: BinaryClassification needs you specify manually the threshold, by default 0.5.  How do calculate a different one, the best one?

Answer (score 8):

The previous answers assume that you indeed calculated TP/Sens yourself. It's a bad idea to do this manually, it's easy to make mistakes with the calculations, rather use a library function for all of this.

the plot_roc function in scikit_lean does exactly what you need:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

The essential part of the code is:

```
  for i in range(n_classes):
      fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
      roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

Comment: How to calculate y_score?

Answer (score 8):

There is a library called [metriculous](https://github.com/metriculous-ml/metriculous) that will do that for you:

```sh
$ pip install metriculous
```

Let's first mock some data, this would usually come from the test dataset and the model(s):

```py
import numpy as np

def normalize(array2d: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return array2d / array2d.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

class_names = ["Cat", "Dog", "Pig"]
num_classes = len(class_names)
num_samples = 500

# Mock ground truth
ground_truth = np.random.choice(range(num_classes), size=num_samples, p=[0.5, 0.4, 0.1])

# Mock model predictions
perfect_model = np.eye(num_classes)[ground_truth]
noisy_model = normalize(
    perfect_model + 2 * np.random.random((num_samples, num_classes))
)
random_model = normalize(np.random.random((num_samples, num_classes)))
```

Now we can use [metriculous](https://github.com/metriculous-ml/metriculous) to generate a table with various metrics and diagrams, including ROC curves:

```py
import metriculous

metriculous.compare_classifiers(
    ground_truth=ground_truth,
    model_predictions=[perfect_model, noisy_model, random_model],
    model_names=["Perfect Model", "Noisy Model", "Random Model"],
    class_names=class_names,
    one_vs_all_figures=True, # This line is important to include ROC curves in the output
).save_html("model_comparison.html").display()
```

The ROC curves in the output:
[image: metriculous ROC curves]

The plots are zoomable and draggable, and you get further details when hovering with your mouse over the plot:

[image: metriculous ROC curve]

Answer (score 7):

You can also follow the offical documentation form scikit:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py

Answer (score 5):

I have made a simple function included in a package for the ROC curve. I just started practicing machine learning so please also let me know if this code has any problem!

Have a look at the github readme file for more details! :)

https://github.com/bc123456/ROC

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, roc_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def plot_ROC(y_train_true, y_train_prob, y_test_true, y_test_prob):
    '''
    a funciton to plot the ROC curve for train labels and test labels.
    Use the best threshold found in train set to classify items in test set.
    '''
    fpr_train, tpr_train, thresholds_train = roc_curve(y_train_true, y_train_prob, pos_label =True)
    sum_sensitivity_specificity_train = tpr_train + (1-fpr_train)
    best_threshold_id_train = np.argmax(sum_sensitivity_specificity_train)
    best_threshold = thresholds_train[best_threshold_id_train]
    best_fpr_train = fpr_train[best_threshold_id_train]
    best_tpr_train = tpr_train[best_threshold_id_train]
    y_train = y_train_prob > best_threshold

    cm_train = confusion_matrix(y_train_true, y_train)
    acc_train = accuracy_score(y_train_true, y_train)
    auc_train = roc_auc_score(y_train_true, y_train)

    print 'Train Accuracy: %s ' %acc_train
    print 'Train AUC: %s ' %auc_train
    print 'Train Confusion Matrix:'
    print cm_train

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
    curve1 = ax.plot(fpr_train, tpr_train)
    curve2 = ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', linestyle='--')
    dot = ax.plot(best_fpr_train, best_tpr_train, marker='o', color='black')
    ax.text(best_fpr_train, best_tpr_train, s = '(%.3f,%.3f)' %(best_fpr_train, best_tpr_train))
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('ROC curve (Train), AUC = %.4f'%auc_train)

    fpr_test, tpr_test, thresholds_test = roc_curve(y_test_true, y_test_prob, pos_label =True)

    y_test = y_test_prob > best_threshold

    cm_test = confusion_matrix(y_test_true, y_test)
    acc_test = accuracy_score(y_test_true, y_test)
    auc_test = roc_auc_score(y_test_true, y_test)

    print 'Test Accuracy: %s ' %acc_test
    print 'Test AUC: %s ' %auc_test
    print 'Test Confusion Matrix:'
    print cm_test

    tpr_score = float(cm_test[1][1])/(cm_test[1][1] + cm_test[1][0])
    fpr_score = float(cm_test[0][1])/(cm_test[0][0]+ cm_test[0][1])

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    curve1 = ax2.plot(fpr_test, tpr_test)
    curve2 = ax2.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', linestyle='--')
    dot = ax2.plot(fpr_score, tpr_score, marker='o', color='black')
    ax2.text(fpr_score, tpr_score, s = '(%.3f,%.3f)' %(fpr_score, tpr_score))
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('ROC curve (Test), AUC = %.4f'%auc_test)
    plt.savefig('ROC', dpi = 500)
    plt.show()

    return best_threshold
```

[A sample roc graph produced by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDPU4.png)

Comment: How to calculate `y_train_true, y_train_prob, y_test_true, y_test_prob` ?

Comment: `y_train_true, y_test_true` should be readily available in a labelled dataset. `y_train_prob, y_test_prob` are outputs from your trained neural network.

Answer (score 3):

When you need the probabilities as well... The following gets the AUC value and plots it all in one shot.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve

plot_roc_curve(m,xs,y)
```

When you have the probabilities... you can't get the auc value and plots in one shot. Do the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

fpr,tpr,_ = roc_curve(y,y_probas)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr, label='AUC = ' + str(round(roc_auc_score(y,m.oob_decision_function_[:,1]), 2)))
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Answer (score 2):

In my code, I have X_train and y_train and classes are 0 and 1. The `clf.predict_proba()` method computes probabilities for both classes for every data point. I compare the probability of class1 with different values of threshold.

```
probability = clf.predict_proba(X_train) 

def plot_roc(y_train, probability):
  threshold_values = np.linspace(0,1,100)       #Threshold values range from 0 to 1
  FPR_list = []
  TPR_list = []

  for threshold in threshold_values:            #For every value of threshold
    y_pred = []                                 #Classify every data point in the test set

#prob is an array consisting of 2 values - Probability of datapoint in Class0 and Class1.
    for prob in probability:
      if ((prob[1])<threshold):                 #Prob of class1 (positive class) 
        y_pred.append(0)                                                  
        continue
      elif ((prob[1])>=threshold): y_pred.append(1)

#Plot Confusion Matrix and Obtain values of TP, FP, TN, FN
    c_m = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)           
    TN = c_m[0][0]                                                          
    FP = c_m[0][1]
    FN = c_m[1][0]      
    TP = c_m[1][1]                                                      

    FPR = FP/(FP + TN)                          #Obtain False Positive Rate                                          
    TPR = TP/(TP + FN)                          #Obtain True Positive Rate                                      

    FPR_list.append(FPR)
    TPR_list.append(TPR)

  fig = plt.figure()
  plt.plot(FPR_list, TPR_list)                                    
  plt.ylabel('TPR')
  plt.xlabel('FPR')
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As The ROC Curve is only for Binary Classification
Then use your data Binarize and raveled

```
# Binarize data for getting AUC 
y_test_bin = label_binarize(y_test, classes=range(y_train.min() , y_train.max())) 
y_pred_bin = label_binarize(Predicted_result, classes=range(y_train.min() , y_train.max()))

# Calculate FP , TP rate
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test_bin.ravel(), y_pred_bin.ravel()  )

# Get AUC , 
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test_bin, y_pred_bin, average='micro', multi_class='ovr')
 
#create ROC curve
plt.plot(fpr,tpr , label= f"AUC = {auc}" , )
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.0]) 
plt.title('ROC')
plt.legend(loc=7)
plt.figure(figsize = [])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using scikit and sklearn

Install package:

```
pip3 install scikit-plot
```

With this solution, you have control on legend and have a baseline AUC of 0.5.
Python code:

```
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scikitplot as skplt

y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_score = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])


fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=1)
auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
auc = format(auc, '.2f')

RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(
    y_true,
    y_score,
    name="micro-average OvR",
    color="darkorange")

plt.plot(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1),np.arange(0,1.1,0.1),linestyle='-.',color='k')
plt.axis("square")
plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
plt.title("Micro-averaged One-vs-Rest\nReceiver Operating Characteristic")
plt.legend({'AUC for classifier: '+str(auc)})
plt.show()
```

More information:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.html

Answer (score 0):

A [new open-source](https://github.com/deepchecks/deepchecks) I help maintain have many ways to test model performance. to see ROC curve you can do:

```
from deepchecks.checks import RocReport
from deepchecks import Dataset

RocReport().run(Dataset(df, label='target'), model)
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]
A more elaborate example of RocReport can be found [here](https://docs.deepchecks.com/en/stable/examples/checks/performance/roc_report.html?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=25009284)

Answer (score 0):

as wrote in w3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_auc_roc.asphow%20to%20install):

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> def plot_roc_curve(true_y, y_prob):
>     """
>     plots the roc curve based of the probabilities
>     """
>
>     fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(true_y, y_prob)
>     plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
>     plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
>     plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
>
> plot_roc_curve(y, y_proba)
> print(f'model AUC score: {roc_auc_score(y, y_proba)}')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using scikit and sklearn

Install package:

```
pip3 install scikit-plot
```

With this solution, you have control on legend and have a baseline AUC of 0.5.
Python code:

```
y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_score = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])


fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=1)
auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
auc = format(auc, '.2f')

RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(
    y_true,
    y_score,
    name="micro-average OvR",
    color="darkorange")

plt.plot(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1),np.arange(0,1.1,0.1),linestyle='-.',color='k')
plt.axis("square")
plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
plt.title("Micro-averaged One-vs-Rest\nReceiver Operating Characteristic")
plt.legend({'AUC for classifier: '+str(auc)})
plt.show()
```

More information:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.html