# sklearn oneclass svm KeyError

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf, n-gram, one-class-classification

My Dataset is a set of system calls for both malware and benign, I preprocessed it and now it looks like this

```
NtQueryPerformanceCounter
NtProtectVirtualMemory
NtProtectVirtualMemory
NtQuerySystemInformation
NtQueryVirtualMemory
NtQueryVirtualMemory
NtProtectVirtualMemory
NtOpenKey
NtOpenKey
NtOpenKey
NtQuerySecurityAttributesToken
NtQuerySecurityAttributesToken
NtQuerySystemInformation
NtQuerySystemInformation
NtAllocateVirtualMemory
NtFreeVirtualMemory
```

Now I'm using `tfidf` to extract the features and then use `ngram` to make a sequence of them

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

nGRAM1 = 8
nGRAM2 = 10
weight = 4

main_corpus_MAL = []
main_corpus_target_MAL = []
main_corpus_BEN = []
main_corpus_target_BEN = []

my_categories = ['benign', 'malware']

# feeding corpus the testing data

print("Loading system call database for categories:")
print(my_categories if my_categories else "all")

import glob
import os

malCOUNT = 0
benCOUNT = 0
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\alika\\Documents\\testingSVM\\sysMAL', '*.txt')):
    fMAL = open(filename, "r")
    aggregate = ""
    for line in fMAL:
        linea = line[:(len(line)-1)]
        aggregate += " " + linea
    main_corpus_MAL.append(aggregate)
    main_corpus_target_MAL.append(1)
    malCOUNT += 1

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\alika\\Documents\\testingSVM\\sysBEN', '*.txt')):
    fBEN = open(filename, "r")
    aggregate = ""
    for line in fBEN:
        linea = line[:(len(line) - 1)]
        aggregate += " " + linea
    main_corpus_BEN.append(aggregate)
    main_corpus_target_BEN.append(0)
    benCOUNT += 1

# weight as determined in the top of the code
train_corpus = main_corpus_BEN[:(weight*len(main_corpus_BEN)//(weight+1))]
train_corpus_target = main_corpus_target_BEN[:(weight*len(main_corpus_BEN)//(weight+1))]
test_corpus = main_corpus_MAL[(len(main_corpus_MAL)-(len(main_corpus_MAL)//(weight+1))):]
test_corpus_target = main_corpus_target_MAL[(len(main_corpus_MAL)-len(main_corpus_MAL)//(weight+1)):]

def size_mb(docs):
    return sum(len(s.encode('utf-8')) for s in docs) / 1e6

# size of datasets
train_corpus_size_mb = size_mb(train_corpus)
test_corpus_size_mb = size_mb(test_corpus)

print("%d documents - %0.3fMB (training set)" % (
    len(train_corpus_target), train_corpus_size_mb))
print("%d documents - %0.3fMB (test set)" % (
    len(test_corpus_target), test_corpus_size_mb))
print("%d categories" % len(my_categories))
print()
print("Benign Traces: "+str(benCOUNT)+" traces")
print("Malicious Traces: "+str(malCOUNT)+" traces")
print()

print("Extracting features from the training data using a sparse vectorizer...")
t0 = time()

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(nGRAM1, nGRAM2), min_df=1, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True) ##############

analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_corpus)

duration = time() - t0
print("done in %fs at %0.3fMB/s" % (duration, train_corpus_size_mb / duration))
print("n_samples: %d, n_features: %d" % X_train.shape)
print()

print("Extracting features from the test data using the same vectorizer...")
t0 = time()
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_corpus)
duration = time() - t0
print("done in %fs at %0.3fMB/s" % (duration, test_corpus_size_mb / duration))
print("n_samples: %d, n_features: %d" % X_test.shape)
print()
```

The output is:

```
Loading system call database for categories:
['benign', 'malware']
177 documents - 45.926MB (training set)
44 documents - 12.982MB (test set)
2 categories

Benign Traces: 72 traces
Malicious Traces: 150 traces

Extracting features from the training data using a sparse vectorizer...
done in 7.831695s at 5.864MB/s
n_samples: 177, n_features: 603170

Extracting features from the test data using the same vectorizer...
done in 1.624100s at 7.993MB/s
n_samples: 44, n_features: 603170
```

Now for the learning section I'm trying to use `sklearn OneClassSVM`:

```
print("==================\n")
print("Training: ")
classifier = OneClassSVM(kernel='linear', gamma='auto')
classifier.fit(X_test)

fraud_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

unique, counts = np.unique(fraud_pred, return_counts=True)
print (np.asarray((unique, counts)).T)

fraud_pred = pd.DataFrame(fraud_pred)
fraud_pred= fraud_pred.rename(columns={0: 'prediction'})
main_corpus_target = pd.DataFrame(main_corpus_target)
main_corpus_target= main_corpus_target.rename(columns={0: 'Category'})
```

this the output to `fraud_pred` and `main_corpus_target`

```
prediction
0   1
1  -1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5  -1
6   1
7  -1
...
30 rows * 1 column
====================
Category
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
...
217 0
218 0
219 0
220 0
221 0
222 rows * 1 column
```

but when i try to calculate `TP,TN,FP,FN`:

```
##Performance check of the model

TP = FN = FP = TN = 0
for j in range(len(main_corpus_target)):
    if main_corpus_target['Category'][j]== 0 and fraud_pred['prediction'][j] == 1:
        TP = TP+1
    elif main_corpus_target['Category'][j]== 0 and fraud_pred['prediction'][j] == -1:
        FN = FN+1
    elif main_corpus_target['Category'][j]== 1 and fraud_pred['prediction'][j] == 1:
        FP = FP+1
    else:
        TN = TN +1
print (TP,  FN,  FP,  TN)
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-1046cc75ba83> in <module>
      7     elif main_corpus_target['Category'][j]== 0 and fraud_pred['prediction'][j] == -1:
      8         FN = FN+1
----> 9     elif main_corpus_target['Category'][j]== 1 and fraud_pred['prediction'][j] == 1:
     10         FP = FP+1
     11     else:

c:\users\alika\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1069         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1070         try:
-> 1071             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1072 
   1073             if not is_scalar(result):

c:\users\alika\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 30
```

1) I know the error is because it's trying to access a key that isn’t in a dictionary, but i can't just insert some numbers in the `fraud_pred` to handle this issue, any suggestions??
2) Am i doing anything wrong that they don't match?
3) I want to compare the results to other one class classification algorithms, Due to my method, what are the best ones that i can use??

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Before calculating the metrics:

You could change your fit and predict functions to:

```
fraud_pred = classifier.fit_predict(X_test)
```

Also, your main_corpus_target and X_test should have the same length, can you put the code where you create `main_corpus_target` please?

> its created it right after the `benCOUNT += 1`: 
>   `main_corpus_target = main_corpus_target_MAL` `main_corpus_target.extend(main_corpus_target_BEN)`

This means that you are creating a main_corpus_target that includes MAL and BEN, and the error you get is:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [30, 222]
```

The number of samples of `fraud_pred` is 30, so you should evaluate them with an array of 30. `main_corpus_target` contains 222.

Watching your code, I see that you want to evaluate the X_test, which is related to test_corpus `X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_corpus)`. It would be better to compare your results to test_corpus_target, which is the target variable of your dataset and also has a length of 30.
These two lines that you have should output the same length:

```
test_corpus = main_corpus_MAL[(len(main_corpus_MAL)-(len(main_corpus_MAL)//(weight+1))):]
test_corpus_target = main_corpus_target_MAL[(len(main_corpus_MAL)-len(main_corpus_MAL)//(weight+1)):]
```

---

May I ask why are you calculating the TP, TN... by yourself?

You have a faster option:

1. Transform the fraud_pred series, replacing the -1 to 0.
2. Use the confusion matrix function that [sklearn offers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).
3. Use ravel to extract the values of the confusion matrix.

An example, after transforming the -1 to 0:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(fraud_pred, main_corpus_target['Category'].values).ravel()
```

Also, if you are using the last pandas version:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(fraud_pred, main_corpus_target['Category'].to_numpy()).ravel()
```

Comment: its created it right after the `benCOUNT += 1`  
`main_corpus_target = main_corpus_target_MAL
main_corpus_target.extend(main_corpus_target_BEN)`
@Noki

Comment: @AliCross Watching your code, I see that you want to evaluate the X_test, which is related to test_corpus (you vectorize the test_corpus outputting X_test). It would be better to compare your results to test_corpus_target, which is the target variable of your dataset, isn't it? These two have the same length, so you would compare the algorithm fairly.

Comment: I used your advice and made the corrections, thanks for that. but I'm still getting that error, but in another term: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [30, 222]`. I don't know how to fix this

Comment: @AliCross the number of samples of fraud_pred is 30, so you should evaluate them with an array of 30. main_corpus_target contains 222. Could you please use the data in test_corpus_target?

Comment: well, I think you're gonna get confused like I am, because when i run `test_corpus_target = pd.DataFrame(test_corpus_target)` then `test_corpus_target= test_corpus_target.rename(columns={0: 'Category'})` i get 102 rows! and when i run `train_corpus_target = pd.DataFrame(train_corpus_target)` then `train_corpus_target= train_corpus_target.rename(columns={0: 'Category'})` i get 57 rows! @Noki

Comment: @niko Any luck figuring out the problem?

Comment: The truth is, I am not able to reproduce your problem... I would need an example of the train and the test :/

Comment: Sorry, the best we can do is use this platform. If someone steps into the same problem, they would not be able to know the solution if we make it private.

Comment: @niko so I finally fixed it  
how can i plot it?  
I used the `tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(fraud_pred, test_corpus_target['Category'].to_numpy()).ravel()` that you recommended. but how can i plot `confusion matrix` and `roc curve` and `the plot to show the decision boundary`

Comment: [Here you have an example of confusion matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix), and [here you have an example of roc curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38467407/5963546)