# Iris dataset - Plotting ROC curve for feature ranking / feature selection and interpreting it

Tags: python, feature-selection, roc, confusion-matrix, iris-dataset

I've been referring to an article on feature selection and need help in understanding how an ROC curve has been plotted.
Dataset used: Iris

One of the ways for feature selection, mentioned in the article is :    Visual ways to rank features

The example below plots the ROC curve of various features.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import auc
import numpy as np# loading dataset
data = load_iris()
X, y = data.data, data.targety_ = y == 2plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
for col in range(X.shape[1]):
    tpr,fpr = [],[]
    for threshold in np.linspace(min(X[:,col]),max(X[:,col]),100):
        detP = X[:,col] < threshold
        tpr.append(sum(detP & y_)/sum(y_))# TP/P, aka recall
        fpr.append(sum(detP & (~y_))/sum((~y_)))# FP/N
        
    if auc(fpr,tpr) < .5:
        aux = tpr
        tpr = fpr
        fpr = aux
    plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label=data.feature_names[col] + ', auc = '\
                           + str(np.round(auc(fpr,tpr),decimals=3)))plt.title('ROC curve - Iris features')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to understand this bit:

```
for threshold in np.linspace(min(X[:,col]),max(X[:,col]),100):
    detP = X[:,col] < threshold
    tpr.append(sum(detP & y_)/sum(y_)) # TP/P, aka recall
    fpr.append(sum(detP & (~y_))/sum((~y_)))# FP/N
```

How can one calculate True Positivity Rate (TPR) & FPR by checking if values of a discrete variable (features) are above a threshold which has been calculated by dividing the range (Max-Min) of the feature in 100 equidistant points?

Here is the resultant ROC curve
[image]

Comment: Not an answer but this is NOT a ROC curve. A ROC curves visits **all** thresholds. Besides not being a ROC curve, a linspace array will be a terrible choice for many real world applications where the data is not close to a uniform distribution, or maybe even a gaussian.

Comment: Can you link to that article?

Comment: Link to the article : https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-for-classification-and-python-tips-for-their-application-10

Comment: This gives me a 404 error.

Comment: But is the question: "how can a ROC curve have 100 equidistant thresholds " or "how is the TPR / FPR calculated"?

Comment: Article title: Feature selection techniques for classification and Python tips for their application

Comment: Both questions are part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with "how can one calculate [a ROC curve] with [a set of] threshold which has been calculated by dividing the range (Max-Min) of the feature in 100 equidistant points?"

## One can't!

A ROC curve shows how TPR and FPR vary **at every possible threshold** by definition. Typically one uses the data itself to establish this set, and takes every unique data point as a threshold.

Limiting it to 100 equally thresholds will give an *approximation* of the ROC curve at best. It might be a decent approximation in case the data is probabilities. In many real world applications where the data is not uniform, or even gaussian, this will be a *terrible* approximation.

**Just don't do it!**

Instead, use a dedicated function from a well-reviewed package such as sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr, tpr = roc_curve(y, X[:,col])
```

To plot it, see the answers of [How to plot ROC curve in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009284/how-to-plot-roc-curve-in-python) for instance.

Now for the second question: how is the TPR / FPR calculated from thresholds, again this is by definition: the TPR or True Positive Rate is the fraction of actual positives that are correctly identified. I'll [refer to the corresponding wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) here, which explains it in more detail that can be covered here.

Comment: Can you point me towards a resource that plots an ROC curve from thresholds in a comprehensive manner?

Comment: Sure, I added a link to a related question in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009284/how-to-plot-roc-curve-in-python